# Is it possible to specify sleep mode "freeze, mem, suspend and etc." using systemctl?

Tags: linux, systemd, embedded

As far as i know we can know we can check which low power configurations are available for our Linux computer by reading `/sys/power/state` file. We can turn low power mode by writing one of this configurations to the same `/sys/power/state` file.

Also we can turn on low power mode using systemd service by calling `systemctl suspend` or `systemctl hibernate`.

In my system I have 3 low power states available: **mem**, **standby** and **freeze**. I figured out, that `systemctl suspend` stands for mem state.

So the question is: Is it possible to choose one of available LP states using systemctl? For my tasks it's crucial to activate sleep mode using systemd services, so other ways to do it are not desirable.

Comment: Have the same question, but not enough karma to post a bounty. You ever get an answer outside of this question?